# Tensorflow Value for attr 'TI' of float is not in the list of allowed values when One Hot Encoding

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, math, google-colaboratory

I have this code that takes a tensor with a shape of `(3, 3)` and reshapes it to  `(9,)`. After that it applies a `one_hot` function but it throws an error.

This is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t1 = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)
t2 = tf.constant([[1], [-1], [1]], dtype=tf.float32)

print(tf.one_hot(tf.reshape(t1, -1), depth=2))
```

And the error is :

```
InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'TI' of float is not in the list of allowed values: uint8, int32, int64
    ; NodeDef: {{node OneHot}}; Op<name=OneHot; signature=indices:TI, depth:int32, on_value:T, off_value:T -> output:T; attr=axis:int,default=-1; attr=T:type; attr=TI:type,default=DT_INT64,allowed=[DT_UINT8, DT_INT32, DT_INT64]> [Op:OneHot]
```

I'm working in a GoogleColab notebook, so I think that the problem might be the version of TensorFlow or the data types of the tensor, but any other solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply cast your tensor to `tf.int32` or similar, since `tf.one_hot` expects integer `indices`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

t1 = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)
t2 = tf.constant([[1], [-1], [1]], dtype=tf.float32)

print(tf.one_hot(tf.cast(tf.reshape(t1, -1), dtype=tf.int32), depth=3))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]], shape=(9, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Or with `depth=2`:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]], shape=(9, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you.